# RewriteRule for htaccess in root of site

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite all URLs to a certain file (/blog/post.php) within certain folders (/blog) except a couple of files (/blog/post.php of course and the root of the directory /blog/index.php or /blog/). I therefore have this:

`RewriteRule ^blog/index.php - [L]`

`RewriteRule ^blog/post.php - [L]`

`RewriteRule ^blog/(.*) /blog/post.php [L,QSA]`

Where the intended result is that all URLs except index.php and post.php get rewritten to post.php
The problem is if I put this in the .htaccess in the site root, when you type just website.com/blog/ it rewrites to page to post.php whereas website.com/blog/index.php doesn't.
If I put the same code in the .htaccess file in the blog folder (but without the word blog in each line) it works as expected/wanted.

I'm very sorry for another RewriteRule question but its a specific example/problem I've not been able to find and I would be very grateful if anyone had any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your single rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/blog/(index|post)\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/(.+)$ /blog/post.php [L]
```